# Use case for WebDriver (https://github.com/huntc/webdriver) to give instructions to any browser

Tags: scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, akka

I'm working on a web scraper using WebDriver and I found this project built in Scala, Spray and Akka (https://github.com/huntc/webdriver), until now, and due to the lack of documentation, I haven't figure out how to send instructions to any browser (I rather use PhantomJs) to do something like:

1. Make a request to an URL.
2. Execute javascript somehow.
3. Inject jQuery (If possible).

Here's the Main.scala code provided in the repo for reference:

```
package com.typesafe.webdriver.tester

import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.pattern.gracefulStop

import com.typesafe.webdriver.{Session, PhantomJs, LocalBrowser}
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import spray.json._
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("webdriver-system")
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)

    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(7.seconds) {
    system.shutdown()
    System.exit(1)
  }

val browser = system.actorOf(PhantomJs.props(), "localBrowser")
browser ! LocalBrowser.Startup
for (
  session <- (browser ? LocalBrowser.CreateSession).mapTo[ActorRef];
  result <- (session ? Session.ExecuteJs("return 5+5",       JsArray(JsNumber(123)))).mapTo[JsNumber]
) yield {
  println(result)

  try {
    val stopped: Future[Boolean] = gracefulStop(browser, 1.second)
    Await.result(stopped, 2.seconds)
    System.exit(0)
  } catch {
    case _: Throwable =>
    }

    }

   }
  }
```